# Unable to deactivate the selection mode with C-SPC

Tags: region, mark, delete-selection-mode

Sometimes I can't deactivate the mode of selecting text which is `C-SPC`. Even if I press it a second time and move the cursor, the text still gets selected. I press `C-SPC` one more time, it activates and selects the text as I move the cursor. Then if I press `C-SPC` again and nothing changes except the label says "Mark deactivated" but really it's not. In order to really deactivate, I have to click somewhere in a buffer by mouse.

Is this a bug?

Comment: `C-SPC` activates and deactivates the mark properly for me. Can you please post the recipe to recreate the misbehavior you see in `emacs -Q`? If you cannot recreate that issue in `emacs -Q`, then you would need to progressively comment out your emacs config in halves till you find the culprit in your code. Also what do you see when you do `C-h k C-SPC`? Does this happen in all the major modes? Does it happen after you do `M-x fundamental-mode`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bug?

No. To deactivate you have to use `C-g` or use one of the commands that operate on the region and deactivate as a side effect. This is described in the manual:

> Whenever the mark is active, you can deactivate it by typing C-g (see Quitting). Most commands that operate on the region also automatically deactivate the mark, like C-x C-u ...

Comment: `C-x C-u` is bound to `upcase-region` by default (from just the excerpts you wrote I got the impression it's supposed to be some kind of deactivate mark command).